# How can I sequentially select and display questions from an array of questions using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm building a quiz app using HTML, CSS and JS. I have all the questions as objects in an array, but the issue is that I want to be able to display one question for the user to answer followed by the next question. So far, I have been unable to do that. I really really need help. I have been struggling for some days now.

```
var score = 0;
var maxQuestions = 0;

var questions = [
{ question: " javaScript is an....... language?",
    anwsers: [ "object-oriented", "object-based", "procedural", "none of the above"],
    correct: 1
    
},
{ question: "which of the following keywords is used a define variable in javaScript",
    anwsers: [ "var", "let", "both A and B", "none of the above"],
    correct: 2

  
}, 
{
    question: "which of the following methods is used to HTML elements using javaScript",
    anwsers: ["getElementsById", "getElementByClassName", "both A and B", "none of the above"] ,
    correct: 1
    
}
];

function showQuestion(questions){
    let ques = document.getElementById('questions');
    let qDiv = document.createElement('div');
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = questions[2]['question'];
    ques.appendChild(qDiv);
    qDiv.appendChild(p);

    let atl = document.querySelectorAll('.alts');
    atl.forEach(function(element, index){
        element.textContent = questions[2].anwsers[index];
        nextQuestion();

        element.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if(questions[2].correct === index) {
                console.log('correct answer');
            } else {
                console.log('wrong answer');
            }
        })
    })  
};

showQuestion(questions);
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});

function nextQuestion() {
    if (maxQuestions !== questions.length) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to refine your question a little? What is your specific difficulty?

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on whether my post was helpful to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will offer some suggestions to help get you on the right track.

First, your app will have to track some state. Specifically, you will need to know the current question the user is viewing and the sum of correct answers the user has chosen (the user's *score*). I would make these items explicit by creating a `state` object:

```
const state = {
  currentQuestionIndex: 0,
  score: 0
};
```

Next, we will modify our `showQuestion` function. Instead of passing to it the list of questions, we will pass the *index* of the question we wish to show. This will allow us later to show the next question when we increment the `currentQuestionIndex` in our state.

I would also recommend dynamically generating the answer option elements based on the `answers` block of the current question. This way, different questions can have different numbers of potential answers.

The following is an example implementation of the function. I am including comments to help clarify:

```
function showQuestion(questionIndex) {
  // Get the current question from the global `questions` array based on the given index.
  const question = questions[questionIndex];
  
  // I am using a naming convention of prefixing the variable names of DOM elements with "$". This is purely a stylistic choice.
  // I have given the element that will contain the question the id of "Question". Title-casing HTML IDs is another stylistic choice.
  const $question = document.getElementById("Question");
  const $div = document.createElement("div");
  const $p = document.createElement("p");

  // Clear the current HTML of the Question and Answers elements.
  $question.innerHTML = "";
  $answers.innerHTML = "";

  $question.appendChild($div);
  $div.appendChild($p);
  $p.textContent = question.question;

  // Loop through each potential answer for current question and
  // create a radio button. This assumes that the "Answers" element is a `<form>`
  question.answers.forEach((answer, answerIndex) => {
    const $input = document.createElement("input");
    const $label = document.createElement("label");

    $label.appendChild($input);
    $label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(answer));

    // Each radio input in the group gets the same name in order to restrict
    // the user to selecting only one.
    $input.name = `Question${questionIndex}`;
    $input.type = "radio";
    $input.value = answerIndex;

    $answers.append($label);
  });
}
```

Next we will permit the user to move to the next question when the button is clicked.

```
const $nextQuestion = document.getElementById("NextQuestion");
$nextQuestion.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Increment the current question index in our state.
  state.currentQuestionIndex += 1;

  // If the new index is equal to the count of questions,
  // we have reached the last question and we will log the score.
  if (state.currentQuestionIndex === questions.length) {
    console.log(`Quiz complete: ${state.score} / ${questions.length}`);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, we will show the next question.
    showQuestion(state.currentQuestionIndex);
  }
});
```

For logging the correctness/incorrectness of the selected answer, instead of adding a listener to each radio input, we will attach a single listener to the Answers form that will listen for the `change` event:

```
const $answers = document.getElementById("Answers");
$answers.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  // Get the current question based on the index in our state.
  const currentQuestion = questions[state.currentQuestionIndex];
  // Get the index of the answer the user selected from the value of the
  // radio button that was selected.
  const selectedAnswerIndex = Number(event.target.value);
  const correctAnswerIndex = currentQuestion.correct;
  const isCorrect = selectedAnswerIndex === correctAnswerIndex;
  
  // Increment state.score if the selected answer was the correct one.
  state.score += isCorrect ? 1 : 0;

  if (isCorrect) {
    console.log("correct answer");
  } else {
    console.log("wrong answer");
  }
});
```

Finally, initialize the quiz by rendering the first question:

```
showQuestion(0);
```

I hope these examples help to put you on the right track. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5wejy2rd/) is a fiddle of the completed example for reference.